# Show there's no $U\subseteq V$ such that $V = W \oplus U$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, direct-sum

> Let $V$, a vector space above $\mathbb{Q}$ such that $\dim(V) = 3$ and let $B$, a basis to $V$ such that $$A:=[T]_B = \begin{bmatrix}
>        2 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
>        1 & 2           & 0 \\[0.3em]
>        0           & 0 & 3
>      \end{bmatrix}$$

Let $W = \ker(T-2I)$. Show there's no $U\subseteq V$ such that $V = W \oplus U$.

**Solution:**

- Let's assume by contradiction there's such $U$.
- Since $T(T-2I) = (T-2I)T$ then $W$ is $T$ invariant. Therefore, the decomposition of $V$ is a direct sum of invariant subspaces (**Why?**)
- Easy to evaluate that the minimal polynomial, $m_T = (x-2)^2(x-3)$. Let $C_1 = \{w\}$, a base of $W$ and $C_2 = \{ u_1, u_2 \}$ a basis of $U$. Then $C = \{w, u_1, u_2\}$ is a basis of $V$.
- Therefore,
  $$[T]_C = \begin{bmatrix}
         2 & 0 & 0           \\[0.3em]
         0 & \alpha           & \beta \\[0.3em]
         0           & \gamma & \lambda
       \end{bmatrix}$$

**I know that there's a theorem claims that if $V = W_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus W_k$ and all of $W_i$ are $T$-invariant then $[T]_B = \text{diag}(A_1,\ldots,A_k)$ and $[T|_{W_i}]_{B_i} = A_i$, but still don't fully understand why it has to be this form.**

From this point, the solution is clear:

$$(x-2)^2 m_C(X) = m_T = \text{lcm} \{ (x-2), m_C(X) \}$$

Which implies $$m_C(X) = (x-2)^2(x-3)$$

Which contradicts the fact that $\deg([T|_U]_{B_2}) = 2$ but it's minimal polynomial has the degree $3$.

I'd be glad to get a clarification for the two question marked with bold.

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to mention that $U$ is required to be $T$-invariant.

Comment: Presumably, the goal is to Show there's no **T-invariant** $U\subseteq V$ such that $V = W \oplus U$.  Is that right?  If so, this would answer your first question.

Comment: One thing is for sure - as stated at the moment, this claim can't be true.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I checked the notes again and it is not mentioned that $U$ must be $T$-invariant, yet those notes are full of mistakes so I guess you are correct.

Comment: @Elimination as others have noted, that must be what they're going for.

Comment: It is convenient to note that it is equivalent to answer the question for $T - 2I$.

Comment: Could you explain please why $[T]_C$ has this form?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to the second question:

We can write any vector $x \in V$ as a block-vector 
$$
x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k) := 
\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_k}
$$
where for each $i$, $x_i \in W_i$ (and is written with respect to the basis $B_i$).

If $[T]_B$ denotes the matrix of $T$ with respect to the matrix described, then by the $T$-invariance of each subspace, we have
$$
[T]_B\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_k} = 
\pmatrix{A_1x_1 \\ A_2x_2 \\ \vdots \\ A_kx_k}
$$
This gives us precisely that $[T]_B = \text{diag}(A_1,\dots,A_k)$.